# Доступ к к n'омму-байту элемента массива через указатель. Как?

Tags: delphi

Имеем

```
var mas: array [1..100] of integer;
    PMas:pointer;
    b:byte;

begin
     PMas:=addr(mas);
    // mas[3]:=$23AFC421, нужно получить 2 байт 3 элемента массива через указатель PMas, т.е. b должно быть равно AF (или при доступе к 2-ому байту мы получим C4? Поправьте меня).   
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще отказаться от указателей:

1. получить элемент массива
2. сдвинуть число влево
3. наложить маску

То есть сделать так (извлекаем биты №8-№15):

```
 program test;

 var Z: array [1..3] of integer = (1000,2000,3000);
 var Y: integer;
 var X: byte;
 var N: integer = 1; { Номер байт для извлечения }

 begin
  Y := Z[2];
  X := (Y SHR (N * 8)) AND $FF;
  writeln(X);
 end.
```